# How to add hyphen in between strings in url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form in which there is one text field and ine submit button.on click of submit button,it goes to next PHP page.The  user can enter text in the text field.The text field can contain n number of text string separated by space.like a user enters text as 
MY name is peter
I want text to change as MY-name-is-peter in url.
when user clicks on submit button.the url should become like submit.php?search=MY-name-is-peter

```
<form action="submit.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

PLease guide on how to add hyphen in the strings in url.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

var handler = function (element) {
  element.form.search.value = element.form.search.value.replace(/ /g, '-');
};

</script>


<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="handler(this);" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

str_replace will work or if you want to use regex you can try preg_replace("/[-]/", " ", $yourString)

Answer (score 0):

You should encode URL before submit it:

```
  $('form').submit(function(){
  var val = $(this).find('#search').val();
  $(this).attr('action','submit.php'+encodeURI(val))
 })
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/e3L3a/